# Setting default value in a Sonata Admin dropdown

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-2.7

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 application that uses the Sonata admin bundle. I have a form defining a Video that allows users to select a Country of origin from a dropdown. Each user entity already has a Country of origin associated with it, so I merely want to give their country as a default value, with the option of selecting others. Here is the code as I have it now:

```
$formMapper
...
    ->add('countryOfOrigin',
          'country_of_origin',
          [ 'data' => $user->getOriginCountry() ])
```

The problem is that this code as it currently exists overwrites any previous selection -- making a user who is from Denmark always have 'Denmark' selected on form reload, even if they had previously told the application to associate the Video with 'Italy.'

**How can I create a default dropdown value without overwriting what the user selects?**

Comment: Do you want to change the origin country? Or is that an extra option you're saving somewhere in an entity?

Comment: do you try empty_data?

Comment: Thanks. After seeing your comment, I tried empty_data. It sort of seems to work, but I then get a different error when saving a new record: "Unable to reverse value for property path "countryOfOrigin": The choice "Denmark" does not exist or is not unique"